# Windows Kernel driver code obfuscation?

Tags: kernel, obfuscation

Does anybody know products which would protect driver from reverse engineering? I thought maybe i should use obfuscators which support kernel code? If yes, can you advice me something, rather free :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that hardcore guys who are knowledgeable in the area of kernel and drivers (which is why they are hardcore) will reverse engineer your stuff easily if they decide to? You won't protect your code from the pros. Most others will probably not even bother dealing with something completely unfamiliar and rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Licence key driver and the drivers which support DRM in Windows are deliberately obfuscated.

Generally speaking though, obfuscation in kernel mode is a bad idea - bugs in kernel mode affect the security of the entire system, crash dumps are difficult to debug and obfuscated code necessarily runs slower than normal code, and slow-downs in ring0 slow down the whole machine.

Putting this together with the fact that drivers are already pretty hard to reverse engineer without some real expertise (i.e. someone who can reverse engineer your driver doesn't want your IPR), the most likely thing you'll be doing by obfuscating your driver is making it more difficult to build, use and maintain your product

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Code Virtualizer is able to obfuscate drivers:
https://oreans.com/codevirtualizer.php